# ''She had been a virgin only twice removed before''

Tags: meaning

I am trying to translate the story [*I Have No Mouth And I Must Scream*](https://wjccschools.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/01/I-Have-No-Mouth-But-I-Must-Scream-by-Harlan-Ellison.pdf) by Harlan Ellison and I just can't grasp the meaning of this sentence:

> that she had been a virgin only twice removed before AM grabbed her and brought her
> down here with us

Specifically the part "had been a virgin only twice removed before".

Can someone explain the meaning of it? How can someone be virgin only twice? Remove what?

Comment: It's not "a virgin only twice" but "a virgin only **twice removed**". I don't understand as I didn't read the [whole text](https://wjccschools.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/01/I-Have-No-Mouth-But-I-Must-Scream-by-Harlan-Ellison.pdf) or know who or what AM is, but "twice removed" is an expression applied to [family relationships](https://www.familysearch.org/en/blog/cousin-chart), like distant cousins.

Comment: *Possibly* that Ellen claimed she had slept with only two men, in other words she would have been a virgin if she hadn't had two previous lovers  *“AM had left her alone, had made her more of a slut than she had ever been. All her talk of sweetness and light, all her memories of true love, all the lies she wanted us to believe”* The sentient Artificial Intelligence that is called AM (I am) is, I think, brainwashing and torturing the small group of humans who have survived WW3.

Comment: The underlying meaning of twice removed is *distantly so*: Far from a virgin.

Comment: It's not _twice removed before_, but _twice removed, before AM grabbed her_.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I think adding "only" negates that "distant" meaning, making "twice" an actual count. So Mari-Lou's interpretation that she's only had sex twice seems more likely.